# Google Plus Share Not worked

Tags: php, google-plus, share, social-networking

I am implementing share button for Google Plus but it is not picking the title, description and image, it only shows URL which I have entered.

I have also tried with virtual host and without virtual host (IP ADDRESS) but it didn't work.

I am sharing code with you:

```
<a href="http://plus.google.com/share?url=http://MYIP/articles/hello-world"> Share </a>

<meta property="og:site_name" content="mysite">
<meta property='og:locale' content='en_US'/>
<meta property="og:title" content="hello worl">
<meta property="og:description" content="Article Inside A Space">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ak1.polyvoreimg.com/cgi/img-thing/size/l/tid/4993075.jpg">
```

Comment: When you say "virtual host" do you mean you are running the server locally on your computer?

Comment: The meta tags are in the head right? The meta tags need to be in the head of the HTML page or at least I strongly recommend you put them there. Any reason you use OpenGraph instead of Google's preferred Schema.org meta data? Google+ will also honor the normal title tag and description meta tag.

Comment: I am not running it locally.

Comment: All meta tags are in the head tag

Comment: I have also tried schema.org but it also not worked:-(

Comment: hey @MuhammadUmair did you found out the solution to your problem.. if yes please help me out.. my google plus share pick other image  from the page but not the desired one